Measure execution time between 2 breakpoints in Visual Studio Code
I have been working for +15 years with Visual Studio, and now I'm working on a Microsoft Business Central project with AL language using Visual Studio Code as IDE.
I have noticed VS Code doesn't mark execution time between breakpoints. I can't find any option, any extension or any post explaining how to get that feature in an easy way.
I know I can use DateTime variables and set it and display elapsed time in console, in example:
// Start
MESSAGE('Starting measurement');
StartDateTime := CURRENTDATETIME;

// My code ...

// End
EndDateTime := CURRENTDATETIME;
ElapsedTime := EndDateTime - StartDateTime;
MESSAGE('Elapsed time: %1', ElapsedTime);

But this kind of solutions doesn't work for me since:

I'm working with many read only code files and I can't even write new runnable code on them.
I need to measure a lot of blocks and compare it with my own methods, so I would need to write a lot of code.

Another option would be to copy and isolate read only blocks in new codeunits, and test over it, but it's not viable since there are hundred of blocks to measure. That's why I prefer a quick and simple solution like a VS Code extension.
EDIT: Since it seems there is no a global solution for any VS Code projects, it could be fine to find a solution/extension just for AL language.
Any ideas?

add log statements to the breakpoint and show the time in there

Anything you find is going to be language-specific, since each language has its own debugger plugin.

@rioV8 since I'm working with AL Language there is no Console.Write() or Log() method, the only available method doesn't show time, it is: procedure LogMessage(EventId: Text, Message: Text, Verbosity: Verbosity, DataClassification: DataClassification, TelemetryScope: TelemetryScope, Dimension1: Text, Value1: Text, [Dimension2: Text], [Value2: Text])

@HolyBlackCat a solution for AL Language also would work for my current project, I edit the answer

look at Log Breakpoints, it will dump the result of an expression to the debug console

There is the "VSCode PerfTips" extension that behaves just like in Visual Studio.
Though I only tested it on Python 3.12.

wow it looks great, I'm busy with another stuff right now, but I'll try it soon, thanks a lot

It doesn't work with AL language in my case. It keeps on displaying Git info instead of the execution time info, maybe uninstalling my Git Lens extension could make it work, I'll tell you when I could test it
